# Sony QX1 Contents Transfer - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: python, sony

I have been trying to use the Sony Camera Remote SDK for controlling a Sony QX1 using python (using https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api)

I managed to take pictures, set all the modes etc. Everything works. When I take a picture, a URL is returned of where it is stored eg. http://192.168.122.1:8080/postview/memory/DCIM/101MSDCF/DSC01111.JPG

But when I try to get the picture in Contents Transfer mode, I get an Internal Server Error 500 ? If I take a picture without SD card, I get a different kind of URL but then I am able to get the picture.

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post a log of the requests and  responses you received?

Comment: If I try using wget, I get the following output:
''http://192.168.122.1:8080/postview/memory/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC00039.JPG?size=Origin' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'http://192.168.122.1:8080/postview/memory/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC00039.JPG?size=Origin' (UTF-8)
--2016-10-18 09:36:55--  http://192.168.122.1:8080/postview/memory/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC00039.JPG?size=Origin
Connecting to 192.168.122.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2016-10-18 09:36:55 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: the mode of the camera was "Contents Transfer". 
Apparently, you can only access the images when the camera is in "Remote Shooting" mode.